# How to add body part, and make it go in the same place as the head

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, adobe

The game I'm making is a top-down which looks a bit like snake.

How can I attach a bodypart to my head (or player), and make it go in the same place where the player goes. I watched some tutorials on YouTube but they were not showing how to do it, and the source code wasn't there either. I would like the code to be as simple as it can be because I am new to programming.

Comment: Why isn't the head inside the players movie clip ?

Comment: Please share what code you're using.  You should demonstrate due diligence in attempting a solution, otherwise you are asking for code gifting, which is frowned upon.  See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask